# How to run flutter project on web when using Stripe, getting "Unsupported operation" error message

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I am using `Stripe` in my Flutter project, and it works fine on Android. However, the same project fails on the web with the following error:

```
Uncaught Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
```

And if i remove `stripe SDK` from the project, it runs fine on the web.

My question is, how can I run the project on the web while still using the Stripe SDK? It's becoming challenging to comment out all the Stripe code when running the project on the web

I also tried to add `flutter_stripe_web 4.5.0`  but that didn't resolve the issue.

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  pay: ^1.1.2
  flutter_stripe: ^9.5.0+1
```